# Improve performance of SVG/CSS spinner

Tags: css, svg

I'm replacing an old gif spinner of an Ember.js app with a new SVG/CSS spinner.

This is the spinner, on my project is saved as `.svg`:

http://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/pJXovM

And I load it with this CSS:

```
background:       no-repeat center;
background-image: url(../images/spinner.svg);
background-size:  65px 65px;
```

The problem is that my Ember.js application does a lot of calculations while the spinner is being shown and this makes the spinner lag.

I have tried encoding the svg in base64 using b64.io but the only gain is the loading time, the performance are the same.

As you can see I already tried to use the GPU using `rotate3d` instead of `rotate`, but I didn't get any performance boost.

Any advice to improve the fluidity of it? Good practices, tricks, and so on are welcome.

Comment: Not sure but maybe switch to dedicated SVG animation? (see for example: https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/ and https://css-tricks.com/svg-animation-on-css-transforms/)

Comment: I have not found any information about performance of SMIL vs CSS :(

Comment: @RobAu even with SMIL the performance are not good enough http://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/oXrgdR?editors=100

Comment: potentially useful:  https://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/

Comment: Hard to get a feel for the issue when the issue isn't reproduced. I am no web-optimize guru, but would like to try the options with your example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here almost certainly lies with the Ember.js app, not with the spinner.

I’d try familiarising yourself with some [profiling tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/cpu-profiling) to figure out what in the Ember app causes the lagging. I’m sure there are steps you can take to improve the performance of your app!

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure SVG solution, with CSS, Javascript is not required
Here is a sample

```css
body {
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  background-color: #333333;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: #e8e8e8;
}
a{
   color: #e8e8e8;
}
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 310;
  stroke-dashoffset: 280;
  animation: dash 2s linear  infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 280;
  }
 
  25% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 15;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 280;
  }
}

.loader {
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from{ transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to{ transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div style=" display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;">
<svg class='loader'
   width="120"
   height="120">
   <circle
    class="progress-ring__circle"
    stroke="#D9DDE4"
    stroke-width="10"
    stroke-linecap="round"
    fill="transparent"
    r="52"
    cx="60"
    cy="60"/>
  <circle
    class="path" 
    stroke="#1a73e8"
    stroke-width="10"
    stroke-linecap="round"
    fill="transparent"
    r="52"
    cx="60"
    cy="60"/>
 
</svg>
  
  <a href="https://codesandbox.io/s/ring-preloader-ui-opeso" target="_blank">[Customize your own ring preloader]</a>
  </div>
```